# Setting zeros in numeric columns in Dask dataframe

Tags: python, dask

This code filters all the columns in a Dask dataframe where the column type is `int` or `float`, and then fills with zero if there's a NaN:

```
df_dask = df_dask.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64'])
df_dask = df_dask.where(df_dask.notnull(), 0)    
print(df_dask.compute())
```

Problem is that the original dataframe has string columns that I need to keep in the final dataframe, but they are dropped in the first filter.
How to keep all the columns and only set with zero where column is numeric and value is NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use standard `fillna` method on the specified columns?

Something like:

```py
select_cols = df_dask.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64']).columns
for c in select_cols:
    df_dask[c] = df_dask[c].fillna(0)
```